# Use Ajax in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm newbie of Zend.
I'm trying to use ajax in Zend. Particularly, i want to do comment that using ajax. 
I have searched on google that i can use Zendx.
I don't know how to use zendx effectively although i have searched and tried implementing them . Thanks

Comment: What exactly you want to do and which JavaScript library you want to use (e.q. JQuery)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using jQuery as it's just so quick and easy to use. As it's doing something like posting a comment you'd need to use this... http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

From the Zend point of view. In your controller have an action like

```
public function commentpostAction()
{
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

    // Add to database logic
    // get post variables as you would do normally
    $commentText = $this->getRequest()->getPost('commentText');

    echo Zend_Json::encode( 'success' );
}
```

Comment: That's right, except now you can use the $this->_helper->json action helper to do the disabling of views and encoding in one step :)

Comment: `echo` in a controller, how could you!?